# Subsequence convergence in hausdorff topological space

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X$ is a Hausdorff topology space, and let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset X$ be a sequence in $X$. Is the following statment true?

> $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has a subsequence convergeing to $x\in X$ if and only if $\forall N\ge 1$, the intersection of any neighbourhood of $x$ with $\{x_n\}_{n=N}^{\infty}$ is nonempty.

I know that if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has a subsequence convergeing to $x$, the latter one is obviously true. But I can't prove the other one. I can't find or construct a convergent subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ since the neighbourhood of $x$ seems to be a little too arbitrary, unlike the case in $R^n$ where I can "shrink" the neighbourhood and selecting corresponding $x_n$.But intuitively it is true.
Can anyone prove or disprove it?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like first countability to actually get a subsequence.  Otherwise there may be too many open sets.

**Example**: Let $X$ be the space of functions $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\to\{0,1\}$ equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence, i.e., the product topology $\{0,1\}^{\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}}$.  Let $f_n\in X$ be $f_n((x_m)_{m\in\mathbb{N}})=x_n$.  Then a diagonal argument (*) shows that $f_n$ has no convergent subsequences.  However, $X$ is compact, so countably compact and hence every countable subset $A$ of $X$ has an accumulation point $x$ (i.e., every neighbourhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$).

(*) The diagonal argument: suppose it has a convergent subsequence $f_{n_k}\to f$.  That means $f_{n_k}(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.  Let $x$ be the sequence that is $1$ at $n_{2\ell}$ for all $\ell$ and $0$ otherwise.  Then $f_{n_k}(x)$ along odd and even $k$ are different constant sequences, contradicting $f_{n_k}(x)\to f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

It’s false as stated.

Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, and let $X=\Bbb N\cup\{\mathscr{U}\}$. Points of $\Bbb N$ are isolated, and the sets $\{\mathscr{U}\}\cup U$ for $U\in\mathscr{U}$ form a nbhd base at $\mathscr{U}$. In other words, the topology on $X$ is

$$\tau=\wp(\Bbb N)\cup\big\{\{\mathscr{U}\}\cup U:U\in\mathscr{U}\big\}\;.$$

Let $\sigma=\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$; every open nbhd of $\mathscr{U}$ has nonempty intersection with $\Bbb N$, but no subsequence of $\sigma$ converges to $\mathscr{U}$.

To see this, suppose that $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\sigma$ that converges to $\mathscr{U}$, and let $A=\{n_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$. If $A\notin\mathscr{U}$, then $\Bbb N\setminus A\in\mathscr{U}$, and $\{\mathscr{U}\}\cup(\Bbb N\setminus A)$ is an open nbhd of $\mathscr{U}$ disjoint from $A$; this is impossible, $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\mathscr{U}$, so $A\in\mathscr{U}$. Let $A_0=\{n_k:k\text{ is even}\}$ and $A_1=\{n_k:k\text{ is odd}\}$. Exactly one of $A_0$ and $A_1$ belongs to the ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$; without loss of generality suppose that $A_0\in\mathscr{U}$. Then on the one hand $\langle n_k:k\in A_1\rangle$ converges to $\mathscr{U}$, since it’s a subsequence of $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, but on the other hand $\{\mathscr{U}\}\cup A_0$ is an open nbhd of $\mathscr{U}$ disjoint from $A_1$. This contradiction shows that $\sigma$ cannot in fact have a subsequence converging to $\mathscr{U}$.

The problem is that $X$ is not a [Fréchet-Uryson space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space): the topology at the point $\mathscr{U}$ is too far away from being first countable.